# How to make a square inscribed in a circle?

Tags: python

I have to write a function in which there is a square inscribed in a circle. The corners of the square touch the circle's perimeter.

The function call for `find_area(4)` should have a return value of `18.2400`.
But I think the fact that I'm trying to incorporate a square root is messing with the code and not giving me any values. 
Here is what I got so far:

```
import math

def find_area(r):
    # area: area of circle - area of square

    s = math.sqrt(2)
    sidesquare = ( s * ((r*2) / 2)
    square = ( sidesquare * 2)** 2
    circle = (3.14 * r)** 2
    area = circle - square
    return (area)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Testing compute() with r = 4:' + str(find_area(4)))
```

Comment: Just a heads-up—you can use `math.pi` to get more precision than just 3.14.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code, mainly you are using few unrequired parenthesis. Hope the below code should help you.

```
def find_area(r):
    s = math.sqrt(2)
    sidesquare = s * r * 2 / 2
    square = (sidesquare * 2) ** 2
    circle = 3.14 * r ** 2
    area = circle - square
    return area
```

Comment: Thank you sosososo much! I removed the parentheses and made a change to the formula for square, since I realized I already found the side. :)

Comment: Unrequired parenthesis don't cause bugs - wrong ones do. Highlighting the functional difference between your code and the code above will make this a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you crunch the math through by hand a bit more, you will find that the area of the square is `2 * r ** 2` and the circle is `pi * r ** 2`, so your function reduces to

```
from math import pi

def find_area(r):
    return (pi - 2.) * r ** 2
```

or, if you insist on pi == 3.14,

```
find_area = lambda r: 1.14 * r ** 2
```